# 7 fractions sorted in an array, added together then reduced. in java

Tags: java, arrays, class, sorting, fractions

Here is my problem, I need to create a program that runs the following instructions.

> Create java class named Fraction. This class is used to represent a
>   ratio of two integers. Include mutator methods that allow the user to
>   set the numerator and the denominator. Also include a method to
>   display the fraction on the screen as a ration (e.g. 5/9). This method
>   does not need to reduce the fraction to lowest terms.
>
> The fraction class should contain the following:
>
> - Private instance variables to store the numerator, denominator, and the ratio_value.
> - Constructor(s) that set all of the instance variables.
> - Public methods to get and set the instance variables.
> - A public method named reduce( ) that returns lowest terms of a fraction.
> - A public method named toString( ) that returns a String containing the  fraction as a ratio.
> - A private method name gcd() that return the greatest common divisor of two integers.
>
> Create a test program that allows the user to create array of 7
>   fractions. Then the program will sort the fraction in ascending order.
>   The highest and the lowest fractions are thrown away and the remaining
>   fractions are added together. The program should display all the
>   fractions and their sum. The sum should be reduced to lowest terms and
>   displayed on the screen. For example, if the sum is 20/60, the program
>   should display 1/3.
>
> Write a sort method in the test program to sort the array of fractions
>   and calculate the sum.
>
> Assume you have the following 7 fractions: 6/7, 2/4, 3/4, 3/18, 1/8,
>   10/20, 2/6, then an example of the output after throwing away the
>   lowest and the largest fractions, will be:
>
> 3 / 18 + 2 / 6 + 2 / 4 + 10 / 20 +  3 / 4 = 9 / 4

I completely lost on how to solve this and stuck where I am at. Below is a copy of my class and .main  file. I have some different things that I have tried commented out with '//' so sorry for the long codes.

```
    package homework_5;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Arrays_hw5 {

    private static final Scanner keyb = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Fraction [] fr = new Fraction[7];
//      Fraction fr1 = new Fraction();
//      Fraction fr2 = new Fraction();
//      Fraction fr3 = new Fraction();
//      Fraction fr4 = new Fraction();
//      Fraction fr5 = new Fraction();
//      Fraction fr6 = new Fraction();
//      Fraction fr7 = new Fraction();
        String reduce = "";
        int numerator = 0, denominator = 0;

        Scanner keyb = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
//      Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);  

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File("fractions"));
            keyb = new Scanner(fis);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


//      keyb.useDelimiter("/");
//      keyb.useDelimiter(" ");
//      fr1.setNumerator(keyb.nextInt());
//      fr1.setDenominator(keyb.nextInt());
//      System.out.println(fr1);
//      fr2.setNumerator(keyb.nextInt());
//      fr2.setDenominator(keyb.nextInt());
//      System.out.println(fr2);
//      fr3.setNumerator(keyb.nextInt());
//      fr3.setDenominator(keyb.nextInt());
//      System.out.println(fr3);
//      fr4.setNumerator(keyb.nextInt());
//      fr4.setDenominator(keyb.nextInt());
//      System.out.println(fr4);
//      fr5.setNumerator(keyb.nextInt());
//      fr5.setDenominator(keyb.nextInt());
//      System.out.println(fr5);
//      fr6.setNumerator(keyb.nextInt());
//      fr6.setDenominator(keyb.nextInt());
//      System.out.println(fr6);
//      fr7.setNumerator(keyb.nextInt());
//      fr7.setDenominator(keyb.nextInt());
//      System.out.println(fr7);



        for (int i = 0; i < fr.length; i++)
        {
            //System.out.println("Enter numerator then denominator, hit enter after each entry: ");
            fr[i] = new Fraction(i, i);
            fr[i].setNumerator(keyb.nextInt());
            fr[i].setDenominator(keyb.nextInt());
            System.out.print(fr[i] + "  "); 
            //System.out.print(fr[i].decimal(numerator, denominator));
        }

//          Arrays.sort(fr);

//          for (int i = 0; i < fr.length; i++)
//              System.out.println(fr[i].decimal(numerator, denominator));

//      Fraction [] frac = {fr[1], fr[2], fr[3], fr[4], fr[5], fr[6], fr[7]};
//      Arrays.sort(frac);
//      for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
//          System.out.println(frac[i]);

    }
    public static void selectionSort(int[]arr)          //sorting array 
    {
        int smallest = 0;
        for (int outer = 0; outer < arr.length - 1; outer++)
        {
            smallest = outer;
            for(int inner = outer + 1; inner < arr.length; inner++)
            {
                if (arr[inner] < arr[smallest])
                    smallest = inner;
            }
            int v = arr[outer];
            arr[outer] = arr[smallest];
            arr[smallest] = v;
        }


    }

}
```

here is my Fraction class

```
package homework_5;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fraction {
    public int numerator = 1;
    public int denominator = 1;
    public int gcd;

    public Fraction() {
        super();
    }
    public Fraction(int n, int d) {
        numerator = n;
        denominator = d;
    }

    public int getNumerator() {
        return numerator;
    }
    public void setNumerator(int numerator) {
        this.numerator = numerator;
    }
    public int getDenominator() {
        return denominator;
    }
    public void setDenominator(int denominator) {
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }


    private static int gcd(int numerator, int denominator) {
        return denominator == 0 ? numerator : gcd(denominator, numerator % denominator);
    }
    public double decimal(double numerator, double denominator) {
        return numerator / denominator;
    }


    public static String reduce(int numerator, int denominator) {
        int gcd = gcd(numerator, denominator);
        return (numerator / gcd) + "/" + (denominator / gcd);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return numerator + "/" + denominator;
    }


}
```

So far all I am able to do is print out the 7 fractions from a .txt file formatted like:6 7 2 4 3 4 3 18 1 8 10 20 2 6
but I want to have a text file formatted like:6/7 2/4 3/4 3/18 1/8 10/20 2/6
I can not figure out how to get a deliminator to read the '/' and the ' '.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: My advice: begin with defining what it is to read one fraction in a file. Then do it N times.

Answer (score 0):

From the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) you can just method chain the delimiter you want onto the constructor for Scanner as a regular expression.

You want whitespace or a `/` symbol, so something like this should work.  Untested, you may have to change the regex. If you do, just use a regex calculator online to fix it properly.

```
Scanner keyb = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(new File("fractions")).useDelimiter("[/ | \s*]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip Ron, I got the program to read the '/' and ' ' by using this code: Now I just need to figure out how to sort, add and do the rest of the steps.

```
Scanner keyb = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
//      Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);  

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File("fractions"));
            keyb = new Scanner(fis);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        keyb.useDelimiter("[/ | *]");
```